# Unable to get data to display in my jList from mysql

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jlist

Unable to get data to display in my jList from mysql.  The data will display in the console with the system.out.println command so I know that my database connection is good.  Here is the section of code that I'm trying to use....

```
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame 
{

{

String dbData;
//String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://your.database.domain/yourdatabasename";
String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/movedb?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";
//String dbClass = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
String query = "SELECT PID, + FirstName, + LastName FROM patientlist";
try 
{
    String selectQuery = "SELECT PID, + FirstName, + LastName FROM patientlist";
    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection (dbUrl, "root", "Menace12!");
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    while (rs.next()) 
    {
        dbData = rs.getString(1) + ", " +  rs.getString(3) + ", " +  rs.getString(2);
        System.out.println(dbData);
        Object FirstName;
        String LastName;
        String PID;

    }
                  DefaultListModel dlm = new DefaultListModel(); //needed to get the items from our combined string data into the list
     //actually adding stuff to list.
   dlm.addElement("PID" + ", " + "LastName" + " ," + "FirstName"); //adding objects to dlm
    //jList1.setModel(dlm); //setting the objects in dlm to our list.


    con.close();
} //end try
catch(ClassNotFoundException e) 
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
catch(SQLException e) 
{
e.printStackTrace();
}       
}
```

Comment: 1) if you have 3 pieces of data to display then you should be using a `JTable` so the data is nicely organized in columns. 2) If the code you posted here works, then the problem is in the code you don't post. If you DefaultListModel is added to a JList and if the JList is added to your frame, then the data should display. Post a proper [mre] that demonstrates the problem using hard coded data. That is first learn how to display a JList on a JFrame. Once that works, then you worry about getting the data from the database.

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html). The ListDemo example is exactly what you need. Adding 1 item to the model is no different than adding multiple items to the model. So if your code is structured the same, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fill the list then do it while you iterate through the resultSet ***inside*** the **while** loop:

```
DefaultListModel dlm = new DefaultListModel();
while (rs.next()) {
    dlm.addElement(new StringBuilder("")append(rs.getString("PID")).append(", ")
                   .append(rs.getString("FirstName")).append(", ")
                   .append(ra.getString("LastName")).toString());
    // Providing that "FileName", "LastName", and "PID" are actally
    // the field names within your database table.
}
jList1.setModel(dlm);
```